# Vim and enhanced commentify weird behavior for C

Tags: comments, filetype-c

I am trying to use EnhancedCommentify plugin for vim and mostly using C. However I can't figure out the issue but when I comment/uncomment it uses `(* ---- \*)` instead of `/* ----- \*/`. I tried to change the plugin itself, it didn't change anything. I also verified wit :set filetype? that vim recognizes the C code, and it does. I even looked for the languages that use `(* *)` for comment and simply removed the lines from the plugin : issue is still there !

It works fine for fortran, python and .vimrc however...

I am kinda puzzled at this, anyone has any idea ?

Also, the plugin did output an error when first using it :

```
Erreur détectée en traitant /home/jacques/.vim/plugin/EnhancedCommentify-2.3/ftplugin/php_enhcomm.vim :
ligne    6 :
E117: Fonction inconnue : EnhCommentifyFallback4Embedded
```

I opened the file and commented the line as i seemed to me it's only relevant for php, but maybe I am wrong...

On another note, I am also trying to remap the smart comment but it seems that I fail, here is the vimrc for now

```
vmap <unique> <C-c> <Plug>VisualComment
nmap <unique> <C-c> <Plug>Comment
imap <unique> <C-c> <ESC><Plug>Comment
vmap <unique> <F3> <Plug>VisualDeComment
nmap <unique> <F3> <Plug>DeComment
imap <unique> <F3> <ESC><Plug>DeComment
```

and i tried with "Guess" instead of "Comment" but it didn't seem to work. I remember doing this a long time ago but can't find my .vimrc from back then...

vmap   VisualComment
nmap   Comment
imap   Comment
vmap   VisualDeComment
nmap   DeComment
imap   DeComment

Comment: Hi @Jacques did you try the answers? Did one solved your problem? If so maybe could you validate the corresponding solutio using the v button next to the voting buttons?

Answer (score 1):

I cannot answer directly your answer, cannot add a comment, but I'll still answer.

It seems like [EnhancedCommentify](https://github.com/hrp/EnhancedCommentify) have not beed updated for 6 years now. I suggest you try another plugin. I personnally use [NerdCommenter](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdcommenter) and love it. You can find other such plugins on [Vim Awesome](https://vimawesome.com/?q=comment).

### Edit

Actually NerdCommenter was my very first comment plugin but I rapidly switched to [Commentary](https://github.com/tpope/vim-commentary), the `gc` mappings sticks very fine in muscle memory. Can't tell why I messed-up.

@Jacques, Commentary has the `:Commentary` command, so for insert-mode mapping, use

```
inoremap <C-c> <C-o>:Commentary<cr>
```

Now, for "unsupported" file formats, from `:h commentary` we can tell that it

> Relies on 'commentstring' to be
>   correctly set, or uses b:commentary_format if it is set.

So you can set the `commentstring` option for any filetype and it will work. See `:h 'commentstring'`. For example to add for python :

```
autocmd! BufNewFile,BufRead *.py setlocal commentstring=#\ %s
```

### Note

1. The python `'commentstring'` is already set in default `ftplugin/python.vim`. It is just an example.
2. This "answer" is off-topic regarding your initial question.

Comment: tpope’s commentary is also good.

Comment: ok i'll try those, thanks for your help !

Comment: could you help me configure tpope's commentary ? I am kinda lost trying to fine tune it, to change the gc / gcc trigger to Ctrl-C and allow it to work on insert mode !

Comment: well I kinda prefered enhancedcommentify coimpared to those two. It allows for insert mode commentary too, and also supports many more files (which i couldn't find how to add for tpope). I guess i'll try and make it work again...

Comment: Commentary mappings are made in a vim way, which is usual with tpope's plugins. I understand you'd like to keep with your habits, but I think you should reconsider. `gcap` and `gciB` are so powerful (and only a few keystrokes). You'd do `daB` to delete a block, `vip` to select a paragraph: that's what these mappings are *vim like*. Besides, `<c-o>` opens any normal mapping to insert mode.